# Adding Links to a D3-generated Table

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to add a link to a table that I create from tabular data using d3. Take a quick look at my snippet:

```js
var data = [
 {'Engine':'Google', 'Founded':'1998', 'Monthly-Visitors':4840295000, 'Site':'www.google.com'},
 {'Engine':'Baidu', 'Founded':'2000', 'Monthly-Visitors':1471079000, 'Site':'www.baidu.com'},
 {'Engine':'Yahoo', 'Founded':'1995', 'Monthly-Visitors':1038375000, 'Site':'www.yahoo.com'},
 {'Engine':'Bing', 'Founded':'2009', 'Monthly-Visitors':203482000, 'Site':'www.bing.com'},
 {'Engine':'AOL', 'Founded':'1991', 'Monthly-Visitors': 39961000, 'Site':'www.aolsearch.com'}
];

var columns = ['Engine', 'Founded', 'Monthly-Visitors', 'Site'];

var table = d3.select('body').append('table'),
  thead = table.append('thead'),
  tbody = table.append('tbody');

thead.append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')
  .data(columns)
  .enter()
  .append('th')
   .text(function(column) {return column; });

var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('tr');

var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(row) {
   return columns.map(function(column) {
    return { column: column, value: row[column]};
   });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
   .text(function(d) {
    if (d.column === 'Site') {
     //console.log('now what?')
    }
    return d.value;

   });
```

```html
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

I have created the table, but I'm not sure how to make the rows containing the websites a clickable link. In the past I have used:

```
d3.select('.links').append('div')
    .append('a')
    .attr('href', 'http://www.google.com')
    .append('text')
    .html('Click here to go to a search engine.');
```

However I can't figure out how to use this approach with a table. I tried appending `a` within a `td` but that didn't work. As I recall, SVG text can be tricky. I think by appending `div` we are not appending SVG text...*I think*..

**Question:** How can I add a `href` property to my `Site` column in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change `.text` to `.html`

and add `<a>` tags in your data like this:

```
'Site': '<a href="www.google.com"> google </a>'
```

Or add conditions in the return statement of your data like this.

```
if (d.column === 'Site') {
  return "<a href="+ d.value +">" + d.value + "</a>"
}
```

Code below:

```js
var data = [
 {'Engine':'Google', 'Founded':'1998', 'Monthly-Visitors':4840295000, 'Site':'www.google.com'},
 {'Engine':'Baidu', 'Founded':'2000', 'Monthly-Visitors':1471079000, 'Site':'www.baidu.com'},
 {'Engine':'Yahoo', 'Founded':'1995', 'Monthly-Visitors':1038375000, 'Site':'www.yahoo.com'},
 {'Engine':'Bing', 'Founded':'2009', 'Monthly-Visitors':203482000, 'Site':'www.bing.com'},
 {'Engine':'AOL', 'Founded':'1991', 'Monthly-Visitors': 39961000, 'Site':'www.aolsearch.com'}
];

var columns = ['Engine', 'Founded', 'Monthly-Visitors', 'Site'];

var table = d3.select('body').append('table'),
  thead = table.append('thead'),
  tbody = table.append('tbody');

thead.append('tr')
  .selectAll('th')
  .data(columns)
  .enter()
  .append('th')
   .text(function(column) {return column; });

var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('tr');

var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
  .data(function(row) {
   return columns.map(function(column) {
    return { column: column, value: row[column]};
   });
  })
  .enter()
  .append('td')
   .html(function(d) {
    if (d.column === 'Site') {
     return "<a href="+ d.value +">" + d.value + "</a>"
    }
    return d.value;

   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Cool idea, never thought about approaching it from the data side.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Alternatively you could add a condition in the html return statement if you know that your data are links, see the edit!

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following to the

```
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.on("click", function(d) { window.open(d.Site, "_blank"); })
```

just after:

```
.append('tr')
```